# Kommasetzung bei der Beschreibung von Eigenschaften mit Bezug zueinander

Tags: adjective, comma, list

Folgendes Beispiel:

> Die intelligente Betriebsweise ist 10 % effizienter als die nicht optimierte, regelbasierte Betriebsweise.

> Die intelligente Betriebsweise ist 10 % effizienter als die nicht optimierte regelbasierte Betriebsweise.

Hierbei möchte ich im hinteren Teil des Satzes ausdrücken, dass die regelbasierte Betriebsweise, nicht optimiert ist. Das nicht optimiert sein steht also in Bezug zu dem regelbasiert sein.

Muss ich in diesem Fall ein Komma setzen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind möglich, und wie Du richtig erkannt hast, drücken Sie unterschiedliche Dinge aus:

> Die intelligente Betriebsweise ist 10 % effizienter als die nicht optimierte, regelbasierte Betriebsweise.

Hier haben wir eine Aufzählung von Adjektiv- Attributen:

Die Betriebsweise ist regelbasiert UND nicht optimiert.

> Die intelligente Betriebsweise ist 10 % effizienter als die nicht optimierte regelbasierte Betriebsweise.

Hier haben wir ein Adjektiv- Atrribut, das die gesamte Wortgruppe näher spezifiziert:

Die regelbasierte Betriebsweise ist also nicht optimiert. Also genau das, was Du ausdrücken willst.

Comment: Danke, das klingt logisch. Eine weitere Frage, für die ich nicht extra ein Thema eröffnen möchte: Wäre es in dem Beispiel auch möglich `nicht-optimierte` statt `nicht optimierte` zu schreiben?

Comment: Vermutlich... mit diesen Bindestrichregeln kenne ich mich nicht aus

Comment: @Emma Das solltest du eher ohne Bindestrich schreiben (vgl. [§26.2.3](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6154))

Comment: @some_user ok danke, ich habe auch nochmal ein neues Thema aufgemacht: [link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/62071/bindestrich-bei-einem-negierten-adjektiv)