# Bindestrich bei einem negierten Adjektiv?

Tags: adjective, hyphen

Folgendes Beispiel:

> Die nicht optimierte Betriebsweise führt zu einem hohen Verschleiß.

> Die nicht-optimierte Betriebsweise führt zu einem hohen Verschleiß.

Sind beide Schreibweisen möglich? Wenn ja, welche ist empfehlenswert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im Prinzip sind m. E. beide Schreibweisen möglich, es hängt davon ab worauf man die Betonung legen möchte. Ist es eine Betriebsweise, die einfach nicht optimiert ist, oder eine (ausdrücklich) nicht-optimierte Betriebsweise?

Im Englischen gibt es dasselbe Phänomen (vgl. etwa *not compliant* vs. *non-compliant*).

Answer (score 2):

Durch die Verneinung von Adjektiven mithilfe der wortgrenzenüberschreitenden Präfixe *nicht-* oder *non-* (mit Bindestrich) ergeben sich im Deutschen sprachwissenschaftlich gesehen Scheinanglizismen. Im Deutschen wird diese Art Sprachfälle vornehmlich mittels Affixe wie *un-* oder *-los* grammatisch gelöst.

Grundsätzlich ist die Verwendung eines präfigierten *nicht* bzw. *non* im Deutschen nicht unmöglich, wobei der maßgebliche Unterschied zwischen den Varianten darin besteht, dass bei jener mit *nicht*/*non* keine relative Darstellung des Sachverhalts erzeugt wird, sondern eine Situationsbeschreibung die gedanklich allein *aufgrund* der Negation des Wortes erst real vorstellbar wird – also zwangsläufigen Anteil der Eigenart vermittelt – und sich gerade deshalb auch nicht auf die bloße Vorstellbarkeit einer so nicht negierten Darstellung des Sachverhalts auswirkt:

> nichtinvasive Medizin

> invasive Medizin

*Nichtinvasive Medizin* ebenso wie *invasive Medizin* sind begriffshalber eigene Teilbereiche in der Medizin und würden in Anbetracht des jeweils dergestalt einhergehenden Vorgehens gedanklich in Beziehung gesetzt werden *können*.

Obigem entsprechend würde daher auch der zweite Beispielsatz im Eröffnungsbeitrag als falsch zu bezeichnen sein müssen, da die Annahme einer notwendigerweise offensichtlichen Optimierung bei Betriebsweisen nicht gegeben sein kann. Überlegungen zu Optimierungen bei Betriebsweisen sind fakultatives Kalkül.